# How can i navigate files retrieved from oneDrive using rest like FileDialog?

Tags: c#, onedrive

I have retrieved a list of files from onedrive using the rest api call. It returns a json object with the file details and whether it is a directory or not.
So if the json object is returned and it has lets say 2 files and a directory , how can i navigate these using something similar to a file.dialog  ?

Update:
I have created a winform and populated the names of the files to a memoedit. so for example it will display

```
testfile1.txt
fileuser.xls
Users         <----- this is a directory
```

I want the user to be able to click on an item and if it is a file it will get the selected value if its a file , but navigate to the sub directory if it is a directory ?

On a side note do i need to check if its a directory then refetch the list of files within that directory via rest again and keep doing that ?

Comment: just create some ui then display items on it.

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: you should check the type and display differently on ui. there are plenty of `simulate windows explorer` projects, you can search.